# How to install diagnostic-updater?

Tags: ros, package, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By mistake I un-installed diagnostic-updater via PyCharm and I am confused how to install same ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280423/how-to-install-diagnostic-updater-?/) by [nalin1997](https://answers.ros.org/users/33375/nalin1997/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-diagnostic-updater
```

?

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0